# ehcache threads crashing if using MaxBytesLocalHeap and MaxBytesLocalDisk

Tags: java, spring, caching, configuration, ehcache

**I have a spring boot application which uses ehcache to cache queries to db.**
If I specify the max number of entries in my cache configuration it works fine. **If however I provide the max size of my cache (which I want), it behaves this way**:

- hangs for a few seconds when starting the application
- generates warning logs with a thread dump

Interestingly, stack trace last log is:

```
at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:100)
```

FYI I'm running Centos 6, within a virtual machine (virtualbox) on a windows win7 host.

[UPDATE] on Centos 7 on bare server, no error logs, but still hangs when it should shut down and same threads dump

- do its process normally
- hangs forever when it has completed its work because several ehcache threads are waiting

**How to fix that error ?** As a workaround I have to force shutdown the application (with applicationContext.close() or kill the process.

*Thread dump when the application starts and hangs for a few seconds*
[image]

*Thread dump when the application completed its work, should shutdown but is stuck because of ehcache cache dedicated threads*
[image]

*Configuration with fixed memory size (not working)*

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig implements CachingConfigurer {


    @Bean
    CacheConfiguration foreNameDemographicStatsCacheConfiguration(){
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("foreNameDemographicStats");
        return cacheConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.setMaxBytesLocalHeap("40%");
        config.setMaxBytesLocalDisk("1G");
        config.addCache(familyNameDemographicStatsCacheConfiguration());
        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*Configuration with fixed elements size (working)*

```
    private Integer maxEntriesLocalHeap=100000;

    @Bean
    CacheConfiguration foreNameDemographicStatsCacheConfiguration(){
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("foreNameDemographicStats");
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(maxEntriesLocalHeap);
        return cacheConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(familyNameDemographicStatsCacheConfiguration());
        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }
```

*Logs when starting the application:*

```
2016-06-29 19:11:09
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode):

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8714984000 nid=0x4621 runnable [0x00007f8700f62000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"_jprofiler_control_sampler" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f86d0026800 nid=0x4616 waiting on condition [0x00007f8700421000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.__ejt_nmp_sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.probe.y.run(ejt:1030)

"Service Thread" #13 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87146c6800 nid=0x4614 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f871467c000 nid=0x4613 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8714679800 nid=0x4612 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8714678000 nid=0x4611 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"_jprofiler_native_sampler" #9 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f86c8012800 nid=0x4610 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"_jprofiler_native_comm" #8 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8714676800 nid=0x45ad runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"_jprofiler_sampler" #7 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8714674800 nid=0x45ac waiting on condition [0x00007f8700e61000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.__ejt_nmp_sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java)
    at com.jprofiler.agent.sampler.Sampler.run(ejt:84)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8714410800 nid=0x45a8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87142e1000 nid=0x4550 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8701164000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000078ad31320> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x000000078ad31320> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87142dd800 nid=0x4548 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8701265000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000078ad314d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x000000078ad314d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8714094800 nid=0x44fd waiting on condition [0x00007f87185c4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.__ejt_nmp_sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:100)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentLoader.loadAgent(AgentLoader.java:135)
    - locked <0x0000000788518988> (a java.lang.String)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.AgentSizeOf.<clinit>(AgentSizeOf.java:38)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.<init>(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:109)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.SizeOfEngineLoader.createSizeOfEngine(SizeOfEngineLoader.java:71)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.SizeOfEngineLoader.newSizeOfEngine(SizeOfEngineLoader.java:59)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.createSizeOfEngine(CacheManager.java:2081)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:453)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
    - locked <0x00000007883d6020> (a net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:270)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1116)
    - locked <0x000000078ae1bca8> (a java.lang.Class for net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1092)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig.ehCacheManager(CachingConfig.java:75)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c.CGLIB$ehCacheManager$4(<generated>)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8728f995.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c.ehCacheManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    - locked <0x000000078ad31ee8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:324)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c.ehCacheManager(<generated>)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig.cacheManager(CachingConfig.java:81)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c.CGLIB$cacheManager$2(<generated>)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8728f995.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c.cacheManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    - locked <0x000000078ad31ee8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:324)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.config.CachingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe5f5c.cacheManager(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AbstractCachingConfiguration.useCachingConfigurer(AbstractCachingConfiguration.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cache.annotation.AbstractCachingConfiguration.setConfigurers(AbstractCachingConfiguration.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    - locked <0x000000078ad31ee8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    - locked <0x000000078ad31ee8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    - locked <0x000000078ad31ee8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    - locked <0x000000078ad31fe8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.TTT.resetContext(TTT.java:223)
    at uk.gov.nationalarchives.ttt.linker.TTT.main(TTT.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87142b2000 nid=0x4543 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87140a9800 nid=0x450e runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87140ab800 nid=0x4510 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87140ad000 nid=0x4511 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87140af000 nid=0x4512 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f87146c9000 nid=0x4615 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 3293

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 50688K, used 22084K [0x0000000787b80000, 0x000000078b400000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 43520K, 36% used [0x0000000787b80000,0x0000000788aeefb8,0x000000078a600000)
  from space 7168K, 87% used [0x000000078ad00000,0x000000078b322398,0x000000078b400000)
  to   space 7168K, 0% used [0x000000078a600000,0x000000078a600000,0x000000078ad00000)
 ParOldGen       total 116224K, used 80K [0x0000000717200000, 0x000000071e380000, 0x0000000787b80000)
  object space 116224K, 0% used [0x0000000717200000,0x0000000717214010,0x000000071e380000)
 Metaspace       used 17988K, capacity 18134K, committed 18304K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2127K, capacity 2150K, committed 2176K, reserved 1048576K

2016-06-29 19:11:15 INFO  MongoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$140b561:73 - using Mongo database: localhost:27017/ttt

2016-06-29 19:11:17 INFO  TTTService:75 - start TTT Process
```

followed guidelines on [how to size ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/cache-size.html),

Comment: Oh gosh, look at how many locks there are in the stack trace. I don't use EHCache, but anyways: Try to update to a recent JVM. From the stack trace I can see its hanging in the sizeof engine, so maybe try to not use the capacity limiting by bytes but just entry count. Specifying the capacity with a byte limit, seems obvious but it is actually very costly and cumbersome. Hopefully it gets better with out using the sizeof thing, than at least you localized the problem source.

Comment: Oops, I just see from your question that you have tried already without specifying the byte limits. Then you should test with another JVM and the recent Oracle one.

Comment: ok thank you @cruftex ! I'll try to upgrade my jvm and give you an update (hopefully next week)

Comment: @cruftex I'm afraid it wasn't because of the JVM, I tried with latest oracle jdk 8 and openjdk 8

Comment: @cruftex why is it very costly and cumbersome to use the byte limit? because it's gonna have to calculate the size when performing eviction instead of just using the nb of elements?

Comment: Just typed the answer but stackoverflow says it is too long by 315 chars :(

Comment: Actually you need to calculate the size on every entry update. Otherwise you don't know whether the limit is reached. All cache operations (insert, update, remove) get additional overhead.

Comment: It is cumbersome, since it actually will never work correctly. You don't know whether an object e.g. a string is referenced by the cached value only. You don't know the fragmentation overhead. The EHCache code obviously depends on the attach API. That is documented and available on an Oracle JVM, but it is not a Java specification. I would prefer my application to be a Java application and not a Oracle JVM application!